# Extracting AMR data from 3GP file

Tags: java, android, audio, amr, 3gp

I have some trouble extracting raw AMR audio frames from a `.3gp` file. I followed the link: "http://android.amberfog.com/?p=181" but instead of "mdat" box type I've got "moov". I read somewhere that "moov" box and "mdat" box location differ from device to device. Does anyone knows how to correctly skip the `.3gp` headers and extract raw AMR data? Below is a code snippet:

```
public AMRFile convert3GPDataToAmr(String rawAmrFilePath) throws IOException {
        if (_3gpFile == null) {
            return null;
        }

        System.out.println("3GP file length: "+_3gpFile.getRawFile().length());
        //FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(_3gpFile.getRawFile());
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(_3gpFile.getRawFile()));
        // read FileTypeHeader
        System.out.println("Available1: "+bis.available());
        FileTypeBox ftypHeader = new FileTypeBox(bis);
        System.out.println("Available2: "+bis.available());
        String header = ftypHeader.getHeaderAsString();
        if(!FileTypeBox.HEADER_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase(header)){
            throw new IOException("File is not 3GP. ftyp header missing.");
        }
        // You can check if it is correct here
        // read MediaDataHeader
        MediaDataBox mdatHeader = new MediaDataBox(bis);
        System.out.println("Available3: "+bis.available());
        header = mdatHeader.getHeaderAsString();
        if(!MediaDataBox.HEADER_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase(header)){
            //here is THE PROBLEM!!!!! - header is "moov" instead of "mdat" !!!!!!!!!!!!!
            throw new IOException("File is not 3GP. mdat header missing.");
        }
        // You can check if it is correct here
        int rawAmrDataLength = mdatHeader.getDataLength();
        System.out.println("RAW Amr length: "+bis.available());
        int fullAmrDataLength = AMR_MAGIC_HEADER.length + rawAmrDataLength;
        byte[] amrData = new byte[fullAmrDataLength];
        System.arraycopy(AMR_MAGIC_HEADER, 0, amrData, 0, AMR_MAGIC_HEADER.length);
        bis.read(amrData, AMR_MAGIC_HEADER.length, rawAmrDataLength);
        bis.close();

        //create raw amr file
        File rawAmrFile = new File(rawAmrFilePath);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(rawAmrFile);    
        AMRFile amrFile = null;

        try {
            fos.write(amrData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);         
        }
        finally{
            fos.close();
            amrFile = new AMRFile(rawAmrFile);
        }

        System.out.println("AMR file length: "+amrFile.getRawFile().length());
        return amrFile;
    }
```

Comment: Where is this failing?

Comment: if(!MediaDataBox.HEADER_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase(header)){
            //here is THE PROBLEM!!!!! - header is "moov" instead if(!MediaDataBox.HEADER_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase(header)){

Comment: Instead of mdat the header is moov

Comment: and the raw AMR data is not correct(maybe because of the changed location of the mdat box)

Comment: Are you sure the failure is not file-specific? Maybe you're just using a broken test 3gp file? I am unsure whether i see a problem with the algorithm.

If you parse a non-3gp header (`moov` instead of `mdat`) either your parser needs fixing or you don't know your testfiles.

Comment: @Shark - I use .3gp file from android recorder. I prepare the recorder like this:mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

Comment: after the recording I try to extract raw AMR data.

Comment: from as I know moov box is for video, but it appears as empty? box in audio file too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used some HEX Viewer tool to look into my .3gp file and I saw that mdat box wasn't in the place where the algorithm has looked for, so I decided to read from the stream until I find the mdat box. Now the extraction works ok. I modified MediaDataBox a little bit:

```
public MediaDataBox(FileInputStream is) throws IOException {
        super(is);

        //check the mdat header - if not read until mdat if found
        long last32Int = 0;
        long curr32Int = 0;
        long temp;
        while (is.available()>=8) {
            temp = curr32Int = readUint32(is);          

            //test like this to avoid low memory issues
            if((HEADER_TYPE.charAt(0) == (byte)(temp >>> 24)) && 
                    (HEADER_TYPE.charAt(1) == (byte)(temp >>> 16)) &&
                        (HEADER_TYPE.charAt(2) == (byte)(temp >>> 8)) &&
                            (HEADER_TYPE.charAt(3) == (byte)temp)){

                size = last32Int;
                type = curr32Int;
                boxSize = 8;
                break;
            }
            last32Int = curr32Int;
        }
    }
```

and super class:

```
public _3GPBox(FileInputStream is) throws IOException{
        size = readUint32(is);
        boxSize += 4;
        type = readUint32(is);
        boxSize += 4;
    }
```